# ECONNREFUSED error trying to connect to the database [discord.js, mysql, phpmyadmin]

Tags: javascript, mysql, discord.js

I have a serious problem with the connection of the discord bot (discord.js) to the phpmyadmin database. It all started with the fact that I wanted to install the database on the SAME vps as the bot. I installed the phpmyadmin database according to this guide -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_30P7up2jA. Now yes, on the housting vps page I have added two TCP and UDP rules to the FireWall with port 3306. My code looks like this:

```
console.log("Log")
var con = createConnection({
  host: "46.41.xxx.68",
  user: "bot",
  password: "xxxxxxxxx",
  database: "commands",
})

console.log("Log")

con.connect(err => {
  if(err) console.log(err)
})

console.log("Log")

con.query("SELECT * FROM useCommands", (err, rows) => {
  console.log("Log")
  if(err) console.log(err)

  let sql

  const numberToAdd = parseInt(1)

  if(rows.length < 1) {
    sql = "INSERT INTO useCommands (commands) VALUES ("+numberToAdd+")"
  }else{
    let number = rows[0].commands
    const addNumber = number + 1
    sql = "UPDATE useCommands SET commands = "+addNumber+""
  }

  con.query(sql)
  con.end()

  dataBaseTable.setHeading("DATABASE")
  dataBaseTable.addRow(chalk.bold.greenBright("MYSQL")+chalk.white(" |---| Connect to database ")+chalk.bold.hex("#f57f17")(host))
  dataBaseTable.addRow("Command execution has been registered. Adding to database...")
  dataBaseTable.addRow(chalk.greenBright("useCommands")+chalk.white(" column data updated"))
  dataBaseTable.addRow(chalk.bold.redBright("MYSQL")+chalk.white(" |---| Disconnected from the database"))
  console.log(dataBaseTable.toString())
  dataBaseTable.clear()
```

})

To investigate the matter, I made me receive messages to the console:

```
console.log("Log")
```

I get 3 log results but don't get 4:

```
log
log
log
???
```

Since then, I don't get any more news about the database:

```
con.query("SELECT * FROM useCommands", (err, rows) => {
  console.log("Log") // <- lack
  if(err) console.log(err)
```

After +/- 3 seconds, I only get errors like this from the console:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 46.41.xxx.68:3306
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\olios\Desktop\Moje rzeczy\Avi\Boty\AVI BOT\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\olios\Desktop\Moje rzeczy\Avi\Boty\AVI BOT\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
at Connection.connect (C:\Users\olios\Desktop\Moje rzeczy\Avi\Boty\AVI BOT\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
at Object.run (C:\Users\olios\Desktop\Moje rzeczy\Avi\Boty\AVI BOT\src\commands\log.js:23:9)
at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\olios\Desktop\Moje rzeczy\Avi\Boty\AVI BOT\src\handlers\command.handler.js:176:11)
at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\olios\Desktop\Moje rzeczy\Avi\Boty\AVI BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\olios\Desktop\Moje rzeczy\Avi\Boty\AVI BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\olios\Desktop\Moje rzeczy\Avi\Boty\AVI BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\olios\Desktop\Moje rzeczy\Avi\Boty\AVI BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
```

Information - versions etc:
**package.json**

```
"ascii-table": "0.0.9",
"axios": "^0.21.0",
"canvas": "^2.6.1",
"chalk": "^3.0.0",
"discord-canvas": "^1.4.1",
"discord.js": "^12.5.1",
"discord.js-commando": "^0.10.0",
"forever": "^3.0.4",
"js-helpers": "github:m7rlin/js-helpers",
"js-yaml": "^3.13.1",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"mysql": "^2.18.1",
"nodemon": "^2.0.6",
"remove-suffix": "^2.0.0",
"request": "^2.88.2"

VPS > mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.33, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

System - Ubuntu 18.04
```

If anyone can help, please

Comment: I dont' think that this is in any way related to Javascript - have you checked through a database client like MySQL Workbench whether you can access the database? Usually, this needs to be enabled not only in the firewall, but also in the user management of MySQL (where the access is filtered by IPs or host names)

Comment: Yes, when I connect to the database via the terminal everything works as it should